# Virtual box : Issue connecting to security.ubuntu.com

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox, package-management

I have Windows 7 as host system, and installed Ubuntu 11.10 as guest. I'm using the latest version of VirtualBox.

The networking works fine, as installation completed correctly and I can browse web pages. I had issue of `BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5` when I used `apt-get`. I tried all the workarounds in the web (clearing cache, installing aptitude, removing files from `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial`, getting the key again, disabling `IPv6`, etc). I don't see the `BADSIG` error now. But I get the following error when trying to run `apt-get update`:

```
Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com[IP:91.189.92.166]
```

I cannot ping to `91.189.92.166` either. 
I can ping `www.google.com` and it works.

Any pointers appreciated.
thanks,
bsr

---

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf  
 domain abc.be  
 search abc.be  
 nameserver 10.240.0.x  
 nameserver 193.xx.xxx.55
```

where `abc.be`, etc. are valid values.

Comment: which dns service you r using ?

Comment: One Sero, thank you.. please find the response edited.

Comment: try this nameserver 208.67.222.222 , nameserver 208.67.220.220

Comment: It allowed me to ping, but still lot of errors. I will post the details later today.. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I get two different IP addresses for that query:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
 Name:     security.ubuntu.com
 Address:  91.189.92.167
 Name:     security.ubuntu.com
 Address:  91.189.92.166
```

I am also able to ping both.

---

What settings are you using for your network on VirtualBox? Bridged or NAT?

What, if any, settings are on your Windows 7 firewall?

I would try using a bridged connection and for testing turn the Windows firewall off briefly. (Assuming you are behind a NAT firewall.)